# How do I correctly set up and use a mdadm RAID1 device with dm-integrity?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I would like to set up a two-disk RAID1 mdadm device with the [dm-integrity](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/device-mapper/dm-integrity.html) function for redundancy.

I know how to partition and add drives to a RAID1 device with mdadm, but I don't know how to make sure dm-integrity is set up correctly and since doing this right is essential, I would be glad if someone with more experience could explain a safe way for doing so.

Do I have to add a startup script to open the devices on each boot? Is an action necessary to manually check for errors or is there automatic reporting?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Could you use the comment section to try and explain *what you're trying to accomplish* using simple English without any technical terms, please?  **0:-)**

Answer (score 2):

I used this as an example

https://gist.github.com/MawKKe/caa2bbf7edcc072129d73b61ae7815fb

Format the disk with luksFormat:

```
 dd if=/dev/urandom of=key.bin bs=512 count=1

 cryptsetup luksFormat -q --type luks2 --integrity hmac-sha256 disk1.img key.bin
 cryptsetup luksFormat -q --type luks2 --integrity hmac-sha256 disk2.img key.bin
```

Open/attach the encrypted disks

```
cryptsetup luksOpen disk1.img disk1luks --key-file key.bin
cryptsetup luksOpen disk2.img disk2luks --key-file key.bin
```

Create raid1:

```
mdadm \
  --create \
  --verbose --level 1 \
  --metadata=1.2 \
  --raid-devices=2 \
  /dev/md/mdtest \
  /dev/mapper/disk1luks \
  /dev/mapper/disk2luks
```

Create a filesystem, add to LVM volume group, etc...

```
 mkfs.ext4 /dev/md/mdtest
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that source! Unfortunately, I have two issues with this guide, which are: I don't need encryption or Luks/LVM for these drives at all and I think the default CRC32 checksums are good enough, especially since they are made for file integrity checks. I'd like to keep the formatting as simple and easy as possible on the system resources, so I'd rather just go with integritysetup, but the guide still does not explain how to behave after the RAID array has been created. It shows how to "scrub" the disks manually, but not if there are any particularities to mounting the devices.

Comment: @Prototype700 (1) You can easily replace "hmac-sha256" with another choice from the list supported by the corresponding option of `integritysetup`. You did not specify in your question which checksum you want to use. If CRC32 is good enough, why are you not happy with the integrity protection present in modern hard drives and, on the cable, the SATA standard? (2) After md RAID creation, you use it as usual. Simply view each dmintegrity device as a hard drive that performs more thorough integrity checking than normal hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

After you've created your device use:

```
integritysetup status <name>
```

## Long Answer

In terminal you can use `man dm-integrity` to read your options. Eeryone else can read the same on the internet:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/integritysetup.8.html

#### NAME

```
   integritysetup - manage dm-integrity (block level integrity) volumes
```

#### SYNOPSIS

```
   integritysetup <options> <action> <action args>
```

#### DESCRIPTION

```
   Integritysetup is used to configure dm-integrity managed device-
   mapper mappings.

   Device-mapper integrity target provides read-write transparent
   integrity checking of block devices. The dm-integrity target emulates
   additional data integrity field per-sector. You can use this
   additional field directly with integritysetup utility, or indirectly
   (for authenticated encryption) through cryptsetup.

   Integritysetup supports these operations:

   format <device>

          Formats <device> (calculates space and dm-integrity superblock
          and wipes the device).

          <options> can be [--data-device, --batch-mode, --no-wipe,
          --journal-size, --interleave-sectors, --tag-size, --integrity,
          --integrity-key-size, --integrity-key-file, --sector-size,
          --progress-frequency]

   open <device> <name>
   create <name> <device> (OBSOLETE syntax)

          Open a mapping with <name> backed by device <device>.

          <options> can be [--data-device, --batch-mode,
          --journal-watermark, --journal-commit-time, --buffer-sectors,
          --integrity, --integrity-key-size, --integrity-key-file,
          --integrity-no-journal, --integrity-recalculate,
          --integrity-recovery-mode]

   close <name>

          Removes existing mapping <name>.

          For backward compatibility, there is remove command alias for
          the close command.

   status <name>

          Reports status for the active integrity mapping <name>.

   dump <device>

          Reports parameters from on-disk stored superblock.
```

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, but this does not help me at all. I have read the integritysetup manual, but it doesn't tell me when I have to use which option, specifically. I'm not as unsure about how to create the array any more at this point, as about how it works with an md-device and what I need to open and mount at which point to make sure dm-integrity works correctly. This info doesn't address that at all.

Comment: @Prototype700 The `status` option will report any errors found by integrity. So it only answers one of your questions. Do you want to use journaling in your setup? It is the most bullet proof but also the slowest method.

Comment: Hi, do you know if `status` shows if the array is damaged or also past corrected errors? As far as I've understood it until now, error correction can only be tracked via `dmesg`? Regarding journaling: Isn't that a feature of the file system (Ext 4)? I just now see the `--integrity-no-journal` parameter, is that a default feature?

Comment: @Prototype700 Here is a blog about status: https://unixsheikh.com/articles/battle-testing-data-integrity-verification-with-zfs-btrfs-and-mdadm-dm-integrity.html. As far as `ext4` single disk journaling system that is not the same thing as dm integrity journaling over a RAID array. Setting up dm integrity journals is described here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/dm-integrity.txt I searched on dm integrity and `dmesg` but came up empty handed...

Comment: @Prototype700 Your md RAID device will act on an error reported by the dmintegrity device the same way it would if a hard drive in an ordinary RAID reports an error. You don't need to concern yourself how to query the status of each member dmintegrity device. Just check the status of your RAID as usual, e.g. with `cat /proc/mdstat`.